# VBA formula not working after transfer from excel 2007 to 2012

Tags: vba, excel

This following code is used to calculated Standard Error (Standard Deviation/Number of Samples). However when used on non-contiguous cells it returns #VALUE! instead of the standard error. I have tried to input the formula as an array. It worked previously but stopped working after moving to a new computer with a new version of excel (2007 to 2012)

```
Option Explicit

Function StdErr(numbers As Range) As Double
Dim StdDev As Double
Dim Size As Integer

StdDev = WorksheetFunction.StDev_S(numbers)
Size = WorksheetFunction.Count(numbers)

StdErr = StdDev / Sqr(Size)
End Function
```

Use of the formula in the spreadsheet would be something like {=StdErr(A1,A3,A5)}

Comment: did you place a breakpoint in the Function and see which line it errors on, possibly by checking the results of each line of the function? If not, do so. This will tell you where it's not handling the same, then you can investigate any chances to the new Excel version and adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

It works if you use one contiguous range, such as =StdErr(A1:A5).  When you add the comma it expects you to pass another variable which isn't there.  To allow for an unknown number of variables it gets a little trickier and you have to use a Variant.  See below:

```
Function StdErr(ParamArray Numbers() As Variant) As Double
    Dim StdDev As Double
    Dim Size As Integer


      StdDev = WorksheetFunction.StDev_S(Numbers)
      Size = WorksheetFunction.Count(Numbers)

    StdErr = StdDev / Sqr(Size)
End Function
```

Comment: Oddly enough this stopped the contiguous ranges from working. Now it works for any selection that doesn't include ranges e.g. (A1:A3,B2,B3) or (A1:A3) both do not work but (A1,A2,A3) works